# tar lzma autocompression produces the error "This does not look like a tar archive"

Tags: bash, tar, compression

The following script

```bash
mkdir test && cd test
mkdir files
touch files/{1,2,3}
tar --create --file "test.lzma" files/{1,2,3} --auto-compress
mkdir extracted_files
tar --extract --file "test.lzma" --directory extracted_files --auto-compress
```

produces the following error:

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive

but actually tar+compress and uncompress+untar do happen (files are in place). Why is this happening? Is it some kind of bug in `tar`?

On my system:

```
xz --version
 xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.7
 liblzma 5.2.7
tar --version
 tar (GNU tar) 1.34
file test/test.lzma
 test/test.lzma: LZMA compressed data, streamed
ls test/extracted_files/
 files
```

You can also reproduce it in https://replit.com/languages/bash (with `xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.2` and `tar (GNU tar) 1.34`). But not in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell (with `xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.4` and `tar (GNU tar) 1.30`).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in upstream. Check out https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?63250.

@Sergey Poznyakoff <gray>:

> The "This does not look like a tar archive" is not an error, but a
> warning.  It is produced, in particular, when tar is unable to
> determine file format by signature and file size is less than tar
> block size.  When the signature recognition fails, tar tries to
> determine file format by its suffix.  In this case, it succeeded and
> extracted the files.
>
> I have installed the following fix to recognized
> LZMA files produced by xz:
>
> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/commit/?id=02f9af1b8df67e55ceb19ea1465d210a2fa1f02c
>
> PS: The --auto-compress option is not needed when extracting.